# Google Play keeps injecting the word "Text" into my Database and I can't stop it

Tags: android, google-play

[image: Database Screenshot]
I've written to Google Play's support about this issue. At first the flatly denied it, but after I submitted screenshots, database logs, etc... they said they were "looking into it."

[image: IP Address Traced]

Basically every time I submit my app to Google Play... the word "Text" is inserted into almost every EditText field.  This includes, Comments, Editable profile fields, etc...

[image]

According to the screenshots this appears to be caused by Google Play's automated testing. I've verified that the IP address of the poster does indeed belong to Google.

I've never seen anything like this in over 30 years of programming and I'm at a bit of a loss for what to do... It happens ONLY when I submit an app update to Google Play.

There's really nowhere else I could think of to ask. Has anyone ever SEEN anything like this? How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: So weird, I didn't see never something like this, and at work we have more than 20 apps uploaded to Google Play :O

Comment: That's what makes me think there's something I'm missing. I mean this is a regular app. Regular EditText fields. And Google is just FLOODING my database with this "text" stuff every time I update the app. I mean I know it's coming from the testing... but why am I the only one?

Comment: Are you using firebase?

Comment: Only just started using Firebase a week ago. Was having the problem long before that.

Comment: It's strange, your database is shared with all users? I don't understand the context of your app

Comment: It's a social media app. People edit their profiles, like, make comments, that kind of thing. Nobody has DIRECT access to the database. They have access to perform those actions through my API.

Comment: So pre-laubch tests are doing actions like a normal user setting the word text where they can... And in fact, it's a shared database, no matter if through your api, it's not a local per app database. You could block this group of IPs (Google's testing IPs) in your API to deny access to your database and prevent this "text" injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload your app, it goes through the Pre-Launch Testing, where it will use test devices to automatically click/type/use your app and try to find bugs and see whether it will crash anywhere.

If you don't want this:

- Go to your app in the Google Play Console
- Click Release Management on the left
- Click Pre-Launch Report
- Click the settings tab
- Disable it

Comment: Much obliged. I'm aware of the testing... I wasn't aware it could  be disabled. That's one, possible solution... but I went in to disable it and learned that I had 11 unrelated crash editors. So I don't mind the testing running... I'm just curious if you've ever encountered this whole "text" thing appearing in your database? I mean it's not like it disappears after the testing... Just hundreds of "text" sitting in the database. Any idea if there's a way to simply prevent that? Like am I not protecting the EditText fields adequately or something?

Comment: Meh... Whatever. I don't think I'll find a better answer than this. Thanks!